# ATI-Radeon 9600 Driver is not installing: 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, ati, ppc

Just a heads up, everything here is being done in Ubuntu, just because I already had a PPC disk. Later when I have a better internet connection, I'll use Lubuntu, but this was quicker. I have a PowerMac G5 dual Core, with the default graphics card, the Radeon 9600. Great for low shaders, however I cannot seem to get the driver working. For starters, when I click on "Additional Drivers" within the System Settings, it flashes a window, appears in the launcher, then disappears. So, from the ATI site, I downloaded the 32 Bit Driver in the form of a .run file. I made sure it was an executeable and then ran in through terminal. It seemed to verify and uncompress, however the installer ran into an error, and before I could read it, the window closed itself. Trying through another method I found the error to be:

```
Error: Distro Version entered incorrectly or not supported, use --listpkg to 
identify valid distro versions
Error: Distro Version entered incorrectly or not supported, use --listpkg to  
identify valid distro versions
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.edUSIT
```

Does anyone think that the graphics card would be able to secure a driver even though the architecture that the OS is currently running in is commonly unsupported? Or has anyone else found a way to run the driver for this graphics card correctly?

**It has come to my attention that the driver may not have been released with PPC support, therefore that may be my problem. Can anyone confirm this?**

Comment: Have a look at the q &  a askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513

Comment: 12.6 Doesn't support PPC64 Architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Legacy/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.12&lang=English

you just have to use the `radeon` driver from the official repository, your card is not supported by the fglrx driver.

Comment: Do I just mark as executable and run in Terminal?

Comment: Did not work, the driver gives me an error and the window closes. I'm assuming it's the same error, because the directory is removed.

Comment: @Flabricorn at the end of that page that i have linked there is a download option for a legacy fglrx driver, try to use that one, remember that every legacy driver could be unsupported by todays kernels, also remember to uninstall the previous driver each time you want to install something new.

Comment: That's the download I used... How could I install the other drivers? None of the other installers to my knowledge worked or installed anything.

Comment: Error: `Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version
default:v2:ppc64:lib::none:3.2.0-26-powerpc64-smp; make sure that the version is being
correctly set by --iscurrentdistro

Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.8AJLf5`

Comment: @Flabricorn you have to expect this kind of problem, old driver + new kernel is almost never a good combination, you probably have to patch it, see if this link can help http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/cant-install-ati-catalyst-9-3-in-debian-need-kernel-patch-821270/

Comment: Lemme try that, gimme a minute.

Comment: Hmmm, the patch seems not able to locate some file packages, or move the .patch file to /usr/src/linux